# TypeScript generic map variadic tuple values to nested mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, variadic-tuple-types

I'm trying to make a helper function that takes a nested object like JSON, and allows one to make a deep copy of a nested value at any arbitrary depth. I understand variadic tuple types and can get them to work for just passing around the tuples - but I don't know how to 'map' them to nested Picks of arbitrary depth (it may not even be possible). Here's the best I've come up with - but is still limited to needing to create as many overloads for GetNestedValue as I would care to support. I understand the various errors, I just can't come up with any way to satisfy the compiler and get type completion on the return value.

```js
// K is arbitrary length how to express N accessors deep? in TS without a loop?
type GetNestedValue<K extends string[], O extends any> = O[K[0]][K[1]][K[2]];

function getNestedItem<Keys extends string[], Obj>(
    obj: Obj, ...keys: readonly [...Keys]
): GetNestedValue<Keys, Obj> extends undefined ? undefined : GetNestedValue<Keys, Obj> {
    let level: any = obj;
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (level !== undefined) {
            level = level[key];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    // this will return deepClone(level);
    return level;
}


const obj = {one: 1, two: {three: {four: 4}}};

// I'd prefer 'known' shapes of obj here block form entering invalid keys.
const a = getNestedItem(obj, 'one', 'two');

// here - when arbitrarily trying to grab stuff from unknown inputs - I don't want
// a warning, rather the user would just need to check `if (b !== undefined)`
const b = getNestedItem(obj as any, 'one', 'two');
```

link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGlQSwZ1BDATgIygF0UgnqANgUwDsBzNAC1DIHsB3UNK0fADwAdF8Y4A5BAYz6cYVRHAAm+fKwD80QqAAqAZVA101AK5oEeKlRkBYAFBosrfKADi+NN05p8YgGrxcG-AB5ILB4TFwYDCgSAG0AXQAaUAB5JmZffwRCLAA+UABeGJDwEIAGMLDskIBGAqKAJgKAbmNjADMNQj40KCp5Yhs7QMcASQcAWy98LDgfIkTAxGDicKjo5AArFIAKY1B10CpFgC4YxaiAOiOAa2GYXY54MTbcHBCjg-AzsOMASl3rW3tHFzdPJ5Gc0WaTGfjgjQkdWCjlAsgh+ChhBhH0632crncQ0BeyWoAA3msNgRtAQAG74XC7eDJDKbRY1IwbUB1ESgZZ8NqBUCnHBUOrcs6vfGEpnrKD85ZkimgACE6Uy8MRjiFBMZovVUtwtM1IR5YQZ6vWAF8mLgYBZVYbRRw0BpEIQDYajSLQM6jC6QPQyLBVFBcFqbXb5BIpABhXBtfCS-Dk3CvR3rQP2vAxikMt21IwcwhcrYLWl4yO7YpRNA0Ki7PHkDj4Sssu27AAsRpbDOMnp6AHIxKB2Aj8IhQJ3joRaIRO6AYGR4OY4Hy6fmyAOLMgI3xjsyRP0mIQHFMSHJSa4oD2eTADsZs1z4LSOl9umI+vh+ss81FO5HO++y1RO-HM56S4cKAAC0qhLvISCoBgSB+jgGBYNM9CMMQmDIJOtp1PydSIFQ26NCOY5yKwWhwGBPSgNc47aDQ1JoO2YA3rR9rTFEmDkAOXoWBo5qDuWGi4D2Cw8doSIwgwoB8Eu66gAABuKbLoXKCp+Ai0JiK8smXpy2joZkd5dA4j4DK+iwIHA1JYO+n7fuWf5VEAAlAsgh%20ChhBhH0632crncQ0BeyWoAA3msNgRtAQAG74XC7eDJDKbRY1IwbUB1ESgZZ8NqBUCnHBUOrcs6vfGEpnrKD85ZkilCgmM0XyqW4WmKkI8sIM%20XrAC%20TFwMAsss1oo4aA0iEIGs1WpFoGtRhtIHoZFgqiguCVJrN8gkUgAwrg2vhJfhybhXpb1p7zXgQxSGXbakYOYQuVsFrS8YHdsUomgaFRdnjyBx8IWWWbdgAWLU1hnGR09ADkYlA7AR%20EQoEbx0ItEIjdAMDI8HMcD5dPTZA7FmQAb4x2ZIn6TEIDimJDkpNcUBbPJgB2Mya58FpHS%203TEfXw-WWaaijcDjfveaojfDicdU44oAAtKop-ISCoBgSBujgGBYNM9CMMQmDIIOpp1PydSIFQy6ND2fZyKwWhwH%20PSgNc-baDQ1JoPWYAnqR5rTFEmDkB2ToWBo%20qdvmGi4C2CwsdoSIwgwoB8FO86gAABuKbLwQAhOkmTwoijivKJh6cto8GZGeXQOJeAy3osCBwNSWD3o%20z75m%20VRAA)

Comment: While this concept is possible (theoretically), I'm fairly certain that TSC doesn't support it due to performance tradeoffs in control flow analysis. Also, why not simply use braket notation? (`const value = obj['two']['three']`)

Comment: I was thinking to somehow come up with something simpler - but I wanted this helper function to protect in undefined cases like `obj?.one?.two?.three` and also provide a deep copy so as not to potentially mutate the original object. Also - when used in a generic function, the number of accessors could be totally arbitrary.

Comment: You can combine bracket notation, optional chaining, and your `deepClone` function without an intermediate function: `const clone = deepClone(obj?.['two']?.['three'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll lead off by saying: While a fun thought experiment, I wouldn't recommend this due to the amount of recursion it requires.

It requires two recursive types, A type to get a valid set of keys inferred from an object type, and a getter to access the property given those validated keys. For TypeScript < 4.5, the depth limit will be a tuple of length 10.

Validation:

```
// walk through the keys and validate as we recurse. If we reach an invalid
// key, we return the currently validated set along with a type hint
type ValidatedKeys<K extends readonly PropertyKey[], O, ValidKeys extends readonly PropertyKey[] = []> = 
    K extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest]
        // Excluding undefined to allow `a?.b?.c`
        ? Key extends keyof Exclude<O, undefined>
            ? Rest extends [] 
                ? [...ValidKeys, Key] // case: nothing left in the array, and the last item correctly extended `keyof O`.
                : Rest extends readonly PropertyKey[] // obligatory typeguard
                    ? ValidatedKeys<Rest,Exclude<O, undefined>[Key], [...ValidKeys, Key]> // recurse
                    : never // impossible, we've sufficiently typechecked `Rest`
            : [...ValidKeys, keyof Exclude<O, undefined>] // case: key doesn't exist on object at this level, adding `keyof O` will give a good type hint
        : [...ValidKeys] // case: empty top level array. This gives a good typehint for a single incorrect string;
```

Getter:

```
// access a property recursively. Utilizes the fact that `T | never` === `T`
type GetNestedProp<K extends readonly PropertyKey[], O, MaybeUndef extends undefined = never> = 
    K extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest] 
        ? Key extends keyof O 
            ? Rest extends [] 
                ? O[Key] | MaybeUndef // succesful exit, no more keys remaining in array. Union with undefined if needed
                /* obligatory typeguard to validate the inferred `Rest` for recursion */
                : Rest extends readonly PropertyKey[]
                    // If it's potentially undefined, We're going to recurse excluding the undefined, and then unify it with an undefined
                    ? O[Key] extends infer Prop
                        ? Prop extends undefined
                            ? GetNestedProp<Rest, Exclude<Prop, undefined>, undefined>
                            : GetNestedProp<Rest,Prop, MaybeUndef>
                        : never // impossible, `infer Prop` has no constraint so will always succeed
                    :never // impossible, we've typechecked `Rest` sufficiently
            : undefined // case: key doesn't exist on object at this level
        : undefined; // case: empty top level array
```

In order for a function to correctly infer a generic, that generic needs to be present as a possible argument. What we want is `ValidKeys`, but we can't do that without having `Keys` itself as a potential argument. So we make use of a conditional for the `...keys` argument to force it to resolve.

Regarding the return type, Even though `GetNestedProp` will potentially be a union with `undefined`, the compiler can't infer that it definitely is in the case where your else branch is hit. So you can either make the return type this awkward conditional, or `//@ts-expect-error` the else branch return statement with a simpler return type of `GetNestedProp<Keys, Obj>`. That alternative is included in the playground:

```
function getNestedItem<Obj, Keys extends readonly [keyof Obj, ...PropertyKey[]], ValidKeys extends ValidatedKeys<Keys, Obj>>(
    obj: Obj,
    ...keys: ValidKeys extends Keys ? Keys : ValidKeys
): GetNestedProp<Keys, Obj> extends undefined ? GetNestedProp<Keys, Obj> | undefined : GetNestedProp<Keys,Obj> {
    let level: any = obj;
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (level !== undefined) {
            level = level[key];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

Given a type with an optional property, digging into that property will convert the nested property type into a union with undefined:

```
interface HasOpt {
    a: { b: number };
    aOpt?: {b: number };
}
declare const obj: HasOpt;
const ab = getNestedItem(obj, "a", "b") // number
const abOpt = getNestedItem(obj, "aOpt", "b") // number | undefined
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHcEMBsGtQC4AsBOB7ArgcyYpBTUWfATwGdRIA7AE1ADcYBLGyBQyC8QlfAYwwoy+AHSgAkgDMIPfJD65qoJlUbQWAWABQIIqQA0M0LwSCqeQgJS8qCaCQbNW7OsISVoaKlghNklRBIAB0IkFQRtBGDCADUnNnwaAGlSMgAeJNB8AA92WgpeSBove1AABXQQlCiUkgBtAF1DAHlDOPVk1Kzc-HzjOWKqUoq0KprSRtAAXlBGgD5p0G1QFdBMnLyaAoGShzqVSXwUNYNQEXODo9AAJXwyBAbl1efdAFFsvmgMGhUfDFp8JIVIlEGgPJ5wKAAAaQAD8IgARvC+FCns8VrCTg4Nr0tnoSGhpO9Pt98GlWqB-jRAcCaHM0ejnpjbvdupsKJMGYzGZi6ucRO0WLUyIZag1QLo+Jx8AAuUBUNDIX6gaCA9wqCyUayQEiGah0ZCEaCcdXsAC2oD4aGs-Ds2J6ALoUOIBOkzShIi53OecpZ7hxfUKg2GlSO43q4t0aAR6iwbGtDiiISwGEgKBoXu9PNAguciWFaT9+mJX2p5MMVJpVESczqYsMfPOueFotIDQWul4VmEmazPvl+HoV10TDNQTQZDITBj+EM3AA5EPQGQMJIgXwmL07YEQgp+MQnX7UVo+ys5Y2BU4W-jCaAS6Ty5SAUDq3TI2ApcI5S7QMU7lR539bImFZLxQGjAArW1KHcJUKFVIdoD1Ggfm8aEXVvd1fGgaBQCwJgl0gPC0DQA1olAMJbF7c9+WbVJ30taU5XwMcolBIIVUHfBcLTFAdTEAAVMIKHwocKCIrASLIkJKPcSRrQCKdvFVZQqCtG0+Hce4UF+ABubRtF0eQ+DucTQCCUNqgcLtBCnRCSDEABVBAmHUAAvO5NUkeRYKQNhoQE0AAB8ByHFAoWmKYZihATjyTQgAHF8AQAA5O4XBGIIMjZXFtiKXZyks8NGhaQwAFkdQRfBHOfHK+krF8QRmaswoWGYGXWB08SDAr9ioQ5jlqQx+UuY4-XFXtMVqOq8Qwt0lhPU9mXSmaOQmxbT1WTFmjrNtgtACqSCqmrqWkXQVz4EyyEkDBcJyPxDAVUAzWtQgXW2M1IBUZUNV4-jQBqpgwPAPxcAa2llGkatEkSXtvWAAAqcCYyYOMEATHd8BTNMDTBNQWASTVRt4Q90oi+TjhsoQgfMBHgDh7lfRWgNup2IYHEysMSFqRoGb7XQpGUBB5wocc8hcmBSnB19DAAdXwedeGI5V0f6btCByElUJ8Q0n1O2k9VoCxzH+JhJAcPxfH8JRpdhjbNvRbbdpIcUWYoUbCtGPmHcxTLVr1qs7Yd4PQExJLUvSxJMsLdLDHvMtMorZ9aTmJP9dfel7ZDrM5XDtL7ijyoY-ufRE4OyrqufTPs+9OUWuHMBR3HSdp1VQwoQ9zKIr8ignqtKhtK+2xlzBEGcI8KByGXDBLvwIOa7PevjhHMcJynGc5wVpd4r3PgD2hI9p7XJgNy3exvblW26ElJj8V-NB-0A7oQPcMDIOg-y4M4xDqIDxqaF0hKD8t8WJBDYujDiCFuJaj4iQAyWhtA3TUi5MCWBkr5xcOIc05IEQQVbFPN2-R8rs1mHNUAzRcHDXOJzKyPMGhNBzFeLohDcwJE6OQDIqQWi4LmHMAAFAySCcoKF4IZPyd6co6IEK6hQYUocsQUEkUw8g2gACUud0GRxoNHa8IiFiEKvvIvOWidFcPITw-ahiNERwLtoouLY9GgAAN4MlVO4KB0A5TUAcDMSC+l7YU1AHw-urIfy3neqo5xvYzZBI8aAAAhFFP+tJIkuKztyOJMwPF1BdA0fx3oAC+WRoDCCiekxkJgzD5O5AUhktT7aVJQOYDx-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-HLElBa20pQjjoCEFbRQmMKLhG0KGygABGRYaCbGYPNHwyChh5yVvnDm0DD7KBTKg+M2DLF4NrPnE20YZAUPvp0GAcQoAAAiXgn6wAVJCcAnLQAEgwBAag7gCC8DEB0iFatbL9KA2BGEEKIpj1woG4TJAoSPUVAFSxydXzHjAwiLDMHEiTLNHhiClBxIQsQ8hxDja0AkfgZ+jS24vUUCcaAHtKA+3HuOPUsDfBIMzGg18mgGmtOGDjUZuNPm134Gzf4qMYCabMDYupS1pRdUZi0M5zDbnsPqbgwh0Acbt3jrQP59LgXgtoYHu4PgABmVTHmvNpYy2OptOXZ2obI0eutBXWQ0Fc2MtTnnUtrN8zVgLqA545bjbZ-LDWqD9quCFK+zX3A0ES+18rXW5lVYQFlwbeWfPbr3YIEb02shtfc1oir3W-N9Y7YN4bPmgRDhG2B-Ac2DsTMWxt6r2XTsDee7u-d53+k7ZPALHTK4zSEBY2x4eX9Va-utLt6QSWOtHYgvV+BeaUAFsILcbs-SAAyo5LatrjQABjjRu70cbwNE7RaeONUzyddsp8Vmn3sScABYGebpDnGgArKzhefY40ADZuc882nGgA7ILoXwc40AA5xcS+znGgAnOTsbDnGdy7PWrhe571cXs11mbX2cDeniN4yE3Gv7aXsiORAAQhCDAHEZjcoykXOoBP-Ok-d9T-Qcb6fe5Z97rn3uBfe7F97mX3ulcMPR-xoc2OzR+DmEAA)

Answer (score -1):

Funny how you prefer "known" types and refuse to use unknown, having a whold bunch of anys all over the place. I do not know anything about variadic tuple types, but here you have 3 examples

```
export const getDeepProp = <Obj>(obj: Obj, ...keys: readonly [keyof Obj]) => {
    const send: Record<string, unknown> = {};


    keys.forEach(i=> {
        type current = typeof obj[typeof i];

        send[i] = obj[i] as current;
    });

    return send;
};



export function deepClone <O> (values:O): O {

      if (values == null || typeof values != "object") return values;

const copy: Record<string, unknown> = {};

        for (const attr in values) {
            if (values[attr]) {
                copy[attr] = deepClone(values[attr]);
            }
        }

        return copy as O;
}

export function name<O> (params:O, ...keys: string[]) {
    const a: Record<string,unknown> = {};

    keys.forEach(key => {
        a[key as keyof O] = typeof params[key as keyof O]==="object" ?
        name(params[key as keyof O], ...Object.keys(params[key as keyof O])) : params[key as keyof O];
    });

    return a as O;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately these examples use the top-level keys as potential types for `...keys` which is not the nested keys I am looking for. The result type incorrectly types the return object with the top-level property keys, not the nested key tree.